# Unable to render heatmap using 'props data' in react-highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-hooks, react-highcharts

I am a beginner in React and I am trying to create a heatmap using highcharts-react.
The highcharts configuration works fine when I use a dummy data array and I am able to see the plot.

However, I need to update the heatmap, using the data passed via props. I am formatting the props data using 'useEffect' hook and setting the 'highcharts options' along with the data inside the 'useEffect' function.

In the console, it appears that all the 'highchart options' are set properly, but the plot doesn't appear on the output page.

It would be great if someone could help me understand the issue here and suggest the correct way to create a heatmap using dynamic data.

Thanks in advance.

**My parent component:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Navbar, Container, Row, Col, Nav, Tabs, Tab } from "react-bootstrap";

import axios from "./service/Axios";

import Heatmap from "./Charts/Heatmap";

function FilterLayout2() {
  
  const [heatmap, setHeatmap] = useState({});

 
  useEffect(() => {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    console.log(query);
    query.samples.forEach(function (item) {
      params.append("samples", item);
    });

    query.ac.forEach(function (item) {
      params.append("ac", item);
    });

    async function fetchHeatmapData() {
      const requestHeatmap = await axios.get("/heatmap", { params: params });
      setHeatmap(requestHeatmap.data.counts);
    }    fetchHeatmapData();
  }, [query]);

  return (
    <>
      <Heatmap plotdata={heatmap} />
    </>
  );
}

export default FilterLayout2;
```

**My heatmap component:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsHeatmap from "highcharts/modules/heatmap";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

HighchartsHeatmap(Highcharts);

function Heatmap(props) {
  console.log(props.plotdata);
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({
    chart: {
      type: "heatmap",
      height: 800,
      marginTop: 20,
      marginBottom: 80,
      plotBorderWidth: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect");
    let categoryList = new Set();
    let geneList = new Set();
    let x_temp = [];

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(props.plotdata)) {
      categoryList.add(key);

      x_temp.push(value);
      value.forEach(function (item) {
        geneList.add(item.trna_label);
      });
    }

    const x = x_temp.reverse();

    const data = x
      .map((l, i) =>
        l.map((c, j) => ({
          x: j,
          y: i,
          value: c.count,
          name: c.trna_label,
        }))
      )
      .flat();

    console.log(data);

    const chartOptionsConfig = {
      credits: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      title: {
        text: undefined,
      },

      xAxis: {
        categories: Array.from(geneList),
        labels: {
          rotation: 90,
        },
      },

      yAxis: {
        categories: Array.from(categoryList),
        title: null,
      },

      colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        reversed: false,
      },

      legend: {
        align: "right",
        layout: "vertical",
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: "top",
        y: 25,
        symbolHeight: 280,
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
              if (this.point.value > 0) {
                return this.point.value;
                
              }
            },
            style: {
              textOutline: 1,
            },
            
          },
        },
      },

      tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
          return (
            "<b>" +
            this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] +
            "</b> <br><b>" +
            this.point.value +
            "</b>  <br><b>" +
            this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] +
            "</b>"
          );
        },
      },

      series: [
        {
          name: "Heatmap",
          borderWidth: 1,
          data,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: "#000000",
          },
        },
      ],
    };
    setChartOptions(chartOptionsConfig);
  }, [props.plotdata]);
  console.log(chartOptions);
  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} />
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Heatmap;
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
b
/mnt/data/react_proj/dev_trex_fe/highcharts.src.js:540
  537 | H.neutralColor20})}else this.graph&&(this.graph=this.graph.destroy())};e.prototype.drawPoints=function(){var b=this.chart.renderer;this.points.forEach(function(d){d.graphic&&d.hasNewShapeType()&&(d.graphic=d.graphic.destroy());d.graphic||(d.graphic=b[d.shapeType](d.shapeArgs).add(d.series.group),d.delayedRendering=!0)})};e.prototype.generatePoints=function(){b.prototype.generatePoints.call(this);this.updateTotals()};e.prototype.getX=function(b,e,c){var g=this.center,a=this.radii?this.radii[c.index]||
  538 | 0:g[2]/2;b=Math.asin(d((b-g[1])/(a+c.labelDistance),-1,1));return g[0]+(e?-1:1)*Math.cos(b)*(a+c.labelDistance)+(0<c.labelDistance?(e?-1:1)*this.options.dataLabels.padding:0)};e.prototype.hasData=function(){return!!this.processedXData.length};e.prototype.redrawPoints=function(){var b=this,d=b.chart,c=d.renderer,e,a,h,f,k=b.options.shadow;this.drawEmpty();!k||b.shadowGroup||d.styledMode||(b.shadowGroup=c.g("shadow").attr({zIndex:-1}).add(b.group));b.points.forEach(function(g){var m={};a=g.graphic;
  539 | if(!g.isNull&&a){var r=void 0;f=g.shapeArgs;e=g.getTranslate();d.styledMode||(r=g.shadowGroup,k&&!r&&(r=g.shadowGroup=c.g("shadow").add(b.shadowGroup)),r&&r.attr(e),h=b.pointAttribs(g,g.selected&&"select"));g.delayedRendering?(a.setRadialReference(b.center).attr(f).attr(e),d.styledMode||a.attr(h).attr({"stroke-linejoin":"round"}).shadow(k,r),g.delayedRendering=!1):(a.setRadialReference(b.center),d.styledMode||l(!0,m,h),l(!0,m,f,e),a.animate(m));a.attr({visibility:g.visible?"inherit":"hidden"});a.addClass(g.getClassName(),
> 540 | !0)}else a&&(g.graphic=a.destroy())})};e.prototype.sortByAngle=function(b,d){b.sort(function(c,b){return"undefined"!==typeof c.angle&&(b.angle-c.angle)*d})};e.prototype.translate=function(b){this.generatePoints();var d=0,c=this.options,e=c.slicedOffset,a=e+(c.borderWidth||0),h=f(c.startAngle,c.endAngle),l=this.startAngleRad=h.start;h=(this.endAngleRad=h.end)-l;var n=this.points,q=c.dataLabels.distance;c=c.ignoreHiddenPoint;var v,w=n.length;b||(this.center=b=this.getCenter());for(v=0;v<w;v++){var x=
  541 | n[v];var E=l+d*h;!x.isValid()||c&&!x.visible||(d+=x.percentage/100);var z=l+d*h;var B={x:b[0],y:b[1],r:b[2]/2,innerR:b[3]/2,start:Math.round(1E3*E)/1E3,end:Math.round(1E3*z)/1E3};x.shapeType="arc";x.shapeArgs=B;x.labelDistance=D(x.options.dataLabels&&x.options.dataLabels.distance,q);x.labelDistance=u(x.labelDistance,B.r);this.maxLabelDistance=Math.max(this.maxLabelDistance||0,x.labelDistance);z=(z+E)/2;z>1.5*Math.PI?z-=2*Math.PI:z<-Math.PI/2&&(z+=2*Math.PI);x.slicedTranslation={translateX:Math.round(Math.cos(z)*
  542 | e),translateY:Math.round(Math.sin(z)*e)};B=Math.cos(z)*b[2]/2;var t=Math.sin(z)*b[2]/2;x.tooltipPos=[b[0]+.7*B,b[1]+.7*t];x.half=z<-Math.PI/2||z>Math.PI/2?1:0;x.angle=z;E=Math.min(a,x.labelDistance/5);x.labelPosition={natural:{x:b[0]+B+Math.cos(z)*x.labelDistance,y:b[1]+t+Math.sin(z)*x.labelDistance},"final":{},alignment:0>x.labelDistance?"center":x.half?"right":"left",connectorPosition:{breakAt:{x:b[0]+B+Math.cos(z)*E,y:b[1]+t+Math.sin(z)*E},touchingSliceAt:{x:b[0]+B,y:b[1]+t}}}}k(this,"afterTranslate")};
  543 | e.prototype.updateTotals=function(){var b,d=0,c=this.points,e=c.length,a=this.options.ignoreHiddenPoint;for(b=0;b<e;b++){var h=c[b];!h.isValid()||a&&!h.visible||(d+=h.y)}this.total=d;for(b=0;b<e;b++)h=c[b],h.percentage=0<d&&(h.visible||!a)?h.y/d*100:0,h.total=d};e.defaultOptions=l(C.defaultOptions,{center:[null,null],clip:!1,colorByPoint:!0,dataLabels:{allowOverlap:!0,connectorPadding:5,connectorShape:"fixedOffset",crookDistance:"70%",distance:30,enabled:!0,formatter:function(){return this.point.isNull?
View compiled
m.b.setData
/mnt/data/react_proj/dev_trex_fe/highcharts.src.js:33278
m.b.update
/mnt/data/react_proj/dev_trex_fe/highcharts.src.js:35527
(anonymous function)
/mnt/data/react_proj/dev_trex_fe/highcharts.src.js:31642
(anonymous function)
/mnt/data/react_proj/dev_trex_fe/highcharts.src.js:31626
e.update
/mnt/data/react_proj/dev_trex_fe/highcharts.src.js:31614
(anonymous function)
/src/HighchartsReact.js:55
  52 |   createChart();
  53 | } else {
  54 |   if (props.allowChartUpdate !== false) {
> 55 |     if (!props.immutable && chartRef.current) {
     | ^  56 |       chartRef.current.update(
  57 |         props.options,
  58 |         ...(props.updateArgs || [true, true])
View compiled
▼ 10 stack frames were expanded.
commitHookEffectListMount
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler-tracing.development.js:257
commitLifeCycles
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler-tracing.development.js:317
commitLayoutEffects
node_modules/url/url.js:372
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22122
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22171
invokeGuardedCallback
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22231
commitRootImpl
node_modules/url/url.js:112
unstable_runWithPriority
http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93933:16
runWithPriority$1
node_modules/react-overlays/esm/Modal.js:168
commitRoot
node_modules/uncontrollable/lib/esm/utils.js:5
▲ 10 stack frames were expanded.
performSyncWorkOnRoot
src/models/Keyframes.js:20
  17 |   this.rules = rules;
  18 | }
  19 | 
> 20 | inject = (styleSheet: StyleSheet, stylisInstance: Stringifier = masterStylis) => {
     | ^  21 |   const resolvedName = this.name + stylisInstance.hash;
  22 | 
  23 |   if (!styleSheet.hasNameForId(this.id, resolvedName)) {
View compiled
▼ 13 stack frames were expanded.
(anonymous function)
node_modules/react-overlays/esm/Modal.js:222
unstable_runWithPriority
http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93933:16
runWithPriority$1
node_modules/react-overlays/esm/Modal.js:168
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
node_modules/react-overlays/esm/Modal.js:217
flushSyncCallbackQueue
node_modules/react-overlays/esm/Modal.js:205
flushPassiveEffectsImpl
node_modules/url/url.js:563
unstable_runWithPriority
http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93933:16
runWithPriority$1
node_modules/react-overlays/esm/Modal.js:168
flushPassiveEffects
node_modules/url/url.js:390
(anonymous function)
node_modules/url/url.js:277
workLoop
http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93883:38
flushWork
http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93857:18
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93623:31
▲ 13 stack frames were expanded.
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.
```

Comment: Hi @Anand Maurya, Could you add a sample of your data structure? It would be very helpful if you could update this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-dk725?file=/demo.jsx with data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have added the data here: [link(]https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-smn8j?file=/demo.jsx:9283-9290)

It works when I provide static data. It fails when I pass new data after retrieving it from the API in the parent component.

Comment: Hi @Anand Maurya, There is probably some bug in Highcharts related with updating color axis. If you move the color axis config to the initial chart options, it works fine. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-ch5vy?file=/Heatmap.jsx

Comment: thank you @ppotaczek for your response. Is there any workaround for setting color scale based on user input? The user should be able to choose a color scale and the heatmap should be rendered accordingly.

Comment: You can change color-axis options, but not in the same update as series: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-zzdee?file=/Heatmap.jsx